# A relative JMP in x64

Tags: assembly, x86-64

So I was trying to find some clarification on this and couldnt work it out/not word it correctly for google to give me the correct results so I'm hoping someone might understand me here.

I'm trying to get my head around assembly for x64 for creating function hooks and I need to clarify how a relative jmp works. So lets say I have a function at **0x7FFFFFF0100**0 and I'm about to write a relative jmp at **0x7FFFFFF00016** the difference between these two addresses is **0xFEA(4074)** however I havent written the relative jmp yet so is the relative difference between the addresses from the address im about to write at to the start of the function or is it from the end of the relative jmp I'm about to write?

Using a difference of **0xFEA(4074)**

```
00007FFFFFF0000C mov     [rsp+10h], rbx
00007FFFFFF00011 mov     [rsp+20h], rsi
00007FFFFFF00016 jmp     [rip+FEA]
00007FFFFFF0001C 0
```

Using a difference of **0xFE4(4068)**

```
00007FFFFFF0000C mov     [rsp+10h], rbx
00007FFFFFF00011 mov     [rsp+20h], rsi
00007FFFFFF00016 jmp     [rip+FE4]
00007FFFFFF0001C 0
```

Comment: The offset is added to the address of the instruction following the jump. Note that the syntax you have chosen selects an indirect absolute jump with the location loaded using a RIP-relative address.  This is not the same thing as a relative jump and will not work as expected.

Comment: @fuz ahh thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. How would using a RIP relative address jmp work differently to a relative jump?

Comment: Read the manual: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jmp loading 8 bytes into RIP from memory at a nearby address is completely different from doing `RIP += sign_extended_rel32` with an immediate relative offset.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a JMP instruction in assembly language that you would assemble with an assembler, or you asking how you would encode a JMP instruction in machine code, like the assembler does when assembling?

Answer (score 1):

GCC appears to accept this seemingly reasonable syntax:
`jmp . + 0x12`.  (The NASM equivalent is `jmp $ + 0x12`.  NASM's `$` works the same as GAS's `.`)

Which for me produces **EB 10**, which is maybe not what you'd expect. That's because the offset of 0x12 is added to the *start* of the instruction while the offset encoded in this "short jump" is from the end of itself, thus the two byte difference.

And, as fuz mentioned, an indirect jump is different; its absolute target address comes from a register or memory.  `jmp .+something`  instead calculates an offset at assembly time to reach the address specified using the dot to mean "current location", the start of the current line.

Comment: Indirect jumps aren't relative.  Using the word "offset" seems misleading, but not technically wrong since `rip` is just the offset part of a `cs:rip` logical address.  (But in 64-bit mode, cs.base is fixed at 0, so the linear address equals the offset part of the logical address.)

Comment: I'm not aware of any assemblers that have a syntax that lets you specify the relative displacement for a jump directly in the asm source.  e.g. `jmp +0x10` is a relative jump to that absolute address in most syntaxes, if supported at all.  (So it can only link into a non-PIE executable.)  See discussion in comments on [How can I write a short bitwise code as jmp $ without directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76672749)

Comment: The above `jmp . + 0x12` was using GNU assembler 2.30, nasm 2.13.02 appears to support it with different syntax: `jmp $ + 0x12`

Comment: That's correct, `$` in NASM works the same as `.` in GAS.  The current position before emitting any bytes from the current source line.